# LDAP/AD filter - "objectclass not equal to" is not working

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am working with LDAP Active Directory and trying to list all users. I have this filter which works perfect:

```
(&(objectclass=user)(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)...)(|(userprincipalname=...)(displayname=...)))
```

Unfortunately, we have also a computer units and other devices present in AD with objectclass "user" so with previous filter I got all users, computers, devices, rooms, etc.

These computer and devices have also an objectclass "computer" so I need to extend the filter with objectclass!="computer" in order to list only real users. So far I'd tried these filters, none of them working (no data returned!):

```
(&(objectclass=user)(!objectclass=computer)(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)...)(|(userprincipalname=...)(displayname=...)))
(&(objectclass=user)(!(objectclass=computer))(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)...)(|(userprincipalname=...)(displayname=...)))
(!(objectclass=computer))(&(objectclass=user)(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)...)(|(userprincipalname=...)(displayname=...)))
(!objectclass=computer)(&(objectclass=user)(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)...)(|(userprincipalname=...)(displayname=...)))
```

(real users do not have the objectclass "computer").

I am working with PHP ldap implementation so using an `ldap_search()` method.

The "not equal to" syntax was found e.g. here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx or here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Maybe I could try to filter users where (!CN=Computers) in DN, but first I'd like to filter (!objectclass=computer) as it is more logical for me.

What is the correct syntax for *objectclass != "computer"* expression?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Contrary to the [first link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx) you provided, `(!objectclass=computer)` is not a valid filter expression. It should be `(!(objectclass=computer))`. See RFC 2254:

> filter ::= "(" filtercomp ")"
>
> not ::= "!" filter

So your filter should be

```
(&(!(objectclass=computer))(objectclass=user)(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)...)(|(userprincipalname=...)(displayname=...)))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to get *all* users, you could just do this:

```
(&
   (objectclass=user)
   (!(objectClass=computer))
)
```

It looks like you're trying to get users who are members of specific groups AND who have a specified principalname (right?). If so, you could do:

```
(&
    (objectclass=user)
    (!(objectClass=computer))
    (|
        (userPrincipalName=username@domain.com)
        (displayName=John Doe)
    )
    (|
        (memberOf=CN\=group1,CN\=Groups,DC\=domain,DC\=com)
        (memberOf=CN\=group2,CN\=Groups,DC\=domain,DC\=com)
    )
)
```

These work on my end (you may need to remove whitespace in you PHP code)

Comment: I've tried this one, it is the second filter I've tried:

(&(objectclass=user)(!(objectclass=computer))(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)...)(|(userprincipalname=...)(displayname=...)))

Currently, the EJP's filter is working:

(&(!(objectclass=computer))(objectclass=user)(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)...)(|(userprincipalname=...)(displayname=...)))